# Angular form values to Strapi API

Tags: angular, forms, submit, strapi

I am trying to get the username, email and password values of the form (DOM?) to paste them into the TS file. Reason for doing that is to send this informatie to the API to create a new user in my db. At this moment, when I submit the webform, it will send the (hardcoded) data below (strapi user, user@strapi.io, strapiPassword) which now is a user in the CMS but of course it should be created based on the form values.

username: 'Strapi user',
email: 'user@strapi.io',
password: 'strapiPassword',

Unfortunately the documentation of Strapi (authentication: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/authentication.html#registration) is too short for me to understand with my knowledge.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form #authForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(authForm)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input 
                    type="username" 
                    id="username"
                    name="username"
                    class="form-control"
                    ngModel
                    required
               />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input 
                    type="email" 
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    class="form-control"
                    ngModel
                    required
                    email 
                />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input 
                    type="password" 
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                    class="form-control"
                    ngModel
                    required
                    minlength="6"
                />
            </div>
            <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!authForm.valid">
                {{ isLoginMode ? 'Login' : 'Register' }}
            </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and place them into the following TS;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import axios from 'axios';

// Request API.
// Add your own code here to customize or restrict how the public can register new users.
axios
  .post('http://localhost:1337/auth/local/register', {
    username: 'Strapi user',
    email: 'user@strapi.io',
    password: 'strapiPassword',
  })
  .then(response => {
    // Handle success.
    console.log('Well done!');
    console.log('User profile', response.data.user);
    console.log('User token', response.data.jwt);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle error.
    console.log('An error occurred:', error);
  });

@Component({
    selector: 'app-register',
    templateUrl: './register.component.html'
})

export class RegisterComponent {
    isLoginMode = true;


    onSwitchMode() {
        this.isLoginMode = !this.isLoginMode;
    }

    onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
        const value = form.value;

    }
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: .Hello! What is the issue you have? It comes from Strapi?